# Project Test failing due to Reference Error - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So here’s my code that I am working on. This is for the drum machine project. I have successfully created the buttons and the audio file is played when I click them. I am not able to pass test no 5 in the compiler which says:

"When I click on a .drum-pad element, the audio clip contained in its child  element should be triggered."

Here’s the code:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDom from "react-dom";
import ReactPlayer from "react-player";

const sounds = [
  {
    idnum: "1",
    id: "Q",
    src: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-1.mp3",
  },
  {
    idnum: "2",
    id: "W",
    src: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-2.mp3",
  },
  {
    idnum: "3",
    id: "E",
    src: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-3.mp3",
  },
  {
    idnum: "4",
    id: "A",
    src: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-4_1.mp3",
  },
  {
    idnum: "5",
    id: "S",
    src: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-6.mp3",
  },
  {
    idnum: "6",
    id: "D",
    src: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Dsc_Oh.mp3",
  },
  {
    idnum: "7",
    id: "Z",
    src: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Kick_n_Hat.mp3",
  },
  {
    idnum: "8",
    id: "X",
    src: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/RP4_KICK_1.mp3",
  },
  {
    idnum: "9",
    id: "C",
    src: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Cev_H2.mp3",
  },
];

class Button extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      audioSource: "not clicked",
    };

    this.soundOn = this.soundOn.bind(this);
  }
  soundOn = (info) => {
    var audio = new Audio(info.src);
    audio.play();
  };


  render() {
    const buttonData = sounds.map((info) => (
      <button
        className="drum-pad"
        id={info["idnum"]}
        onClick={() => this.soundOn(info)}
      >
        {info["id"]}
        <audio
          src={info.src}
          className="clip"
          id={info.id}
          type="audio/mp3"
        ></audio>
      </button>
    ));
    return buttonData;
  }
}

export default Button;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Please create a complete working example. You can use https://codesandbox.io for that.

Comment: @Dekel Hi, Here it is: https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-lederberg-oqmbb?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Nothin there. Make sure you saved the code (try to open the link in a new incognito window)

Comment: @Dekel Done. It was taking some time to update. It should be there now.

Comment: Yes, now it works. But I don't see any issue there... there are no errors.

Comment: Yeah. Its working. But it is for a project. The compiler will check the <audio> tag and the audio should be triggered from the <audio> element. My code now uses the <button> element to do it. So essentially because of that, the test is failing and I have been breaking my head over it for 4 hours noe.

Comment: You need to better explain what you need, and if there is an error somewhere - you need to show that error. Otherwise it's really hard to understand.

Comment: The error is that: The <audio> element with id="Q" does not play when the Q .drum-pad is clicked. When you click a button in this page, the buttons onClick method is playing the audio file. I want the <audio> element to play it or trigger it.

Comment: Where do you get this error? Is this some homework that you need to solve?

Comment: Please share the test suite that you say has the failing test.

Comment: This is the cdn for the test suite: https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/v1/bundle.js - Link for the project is https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/front-end-libraries/front-end-libraries-projects/build-a-drum-machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of generating a new instance of an `Audio` object, you need to get a reference to the actual dom object containing the audio and play it from there.

```js
// Using plain javascript
soundOn = (info) => {
  // Trigger the actual play method from the dom element
  // https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp
  var audio = document.getElementById(info.id);
  audio.play();
};
```

You could be a little more react-idiomatic by using refs, but i'd suggest refactoring a little bit and moving each button to a separate component.

```
class SoundButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    // any state or other logic
    this.soundOn = this.soundOn.bind(this)
  }

  audioRef = React.createRef()

  soundOn() {
    // this.audioRef.current will store a reference to the audio node
    // that is being attached to.
    // https://reactjs.org/docs/glossary.html#refs
    this.audioRef.current.play()
  }

  render() {
    const { info } = this.props
    return (
      <button
        className="drum-pad"
        id={info["idnum"]}
        // Since we are playing the sound from the dom component
        // which already has all the sound info, we don't need 
        // to pass the info to the callback.
        onClick={this.soundOn}
      >
        {info["id"]}
        <audio
          ref={this.audioRef}
          src={info.src}
          className="clip"
          id={info.id}
          type="audio/mp3"
        />
      </button>
    )
  }
}

class Buttons extends React.Component {
  // any other logic

  render() {
    return (
      sounds.map(info => 
        <SoundButton info={info} key={info.id} />
      )
    )
  }
}
```

If you are using hooks, you can do the same using `useRef`

```js
const SoundButton = ({info}) => {
  const audioRef = useRef()
  const soundOn = () => {
    audioRef.current.play()
  }

  return (
    <button
      className="drum-pad"
      id={info["idnum"]}
      onClick={soundOn}
    >
      {info["id"]}
      <audio
        ref={audioRef}
        src={info.src}
        className="clip"
        id={info.id}
        type="audio/mp3"
      />
    </button>
  )
}
```

Comment: I have one small doubt here though. How is the sounds array getting passed to the render function? we have not referenced it anywhere in the code.

Comment: The button itself does not need to know about the entire sounds array, only about its own sound. Therefore, in your parent component you loop through the sounds array and for each sound info you render a new child component that receives that piece of info as prop. You can see this happening at the bottom of the refs example (Buttons class).